# Pass xpc_object_t through NSXPCConnection

Tags: objective-c, foundation, xpc, nsxpcconnection

I am new to XPC service programming, and I am trying to share a IOSurface created in a XPC service to the host application. I can setup a simple host and service using NSXPCConnection API, and now I think I am supposed to use these two methods (found in [IOSurfaceAPI.h](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/IOSurfaceAPI_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOSurfaceLookupFromXPCObject)) to pass the IOSurface to the host:

```
IOSurfaceRef IOSurfaceLookupFromXPCObject(xpc_object_t xobj);
xpc_object_t IOSurfaceCreateXPCObject(IOSurfaceRef aSurface);
```

Is there a way I can pass the xpc_object_t using the NSXPCConnection API, or should I work with the C API (as defined in xpc.h)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. [The "Daemons and Services Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW6-DontLinkElementID_4) states that XPC-proxied methods can handle only the following data types:

- Arithmetic types (int, char, float, double, uint64_t, NSUInteger, and so on)
- BOOL
- C strings
- C structures and arrays containing only the types listed above
- Objective-C objects that implement the NSSecureCoding protocol

`xpc_object_t` is just a typedef for `void *`, so it doesn't meet any of those criteria, and I don't see any way to wrap it in something that does. (Trying to convert it to data, or cast it to an appropriately-sized int, won't work.)

On the other hand, on 10.8, `xpc_object_t` also is enough of an Objective-C object to be retained/released with ARC, to be added to Objective-C collections, etc.

It would be easy enough to try passing an `xpc_object_t` over your protocol, just to see if Apple left an undocumented loophole. Try it!

Otherwise, the lower-level XPC API will definitely work:

```
 xpc_object_t message = xpc_dictionary_create(NULL, NULL, 0);
 xpc_object_t xpcSurface = IOSurfaceCreateXPCObject(aSurface);
 xpc_dictionary_set_value(message, "surface", xpcSurface);
 xpc_connection_send_message(connection, message);
```

Comment: Thank you Kurt, I tried to pass an xpc_object_t as an argument of my protocol's method, but this just doesn't work (SIGABRT at runtime, no compiler errors). No loopholes unfortunately!!
So I tried the other way, but as it seems it is not straightforward to mix NSXPCConnection wrapper code with C API: as far as I can understand, the wrapper hides its xpc_connection_t reference in a private ivar ( void *_xconnection ). But this is another topic.
So, to answer my own question, it seems that IOSurfaceRef isn't simply compatible with the Foundation's Objective-C wrapper..

Comment: That's what I expected. I highly recommend filing a bug with Apple -- if people complain about a bug, it makes it more likely that they will fix it.

Comment: Bug filed with ID 12942765. Thanks Kurt!

Comment: Any news from the bug report 12942765 ?